# SSL Handshake Issue

Tags: iis, ssl, internet-explorer

Our setup is like this, we have a webserver that runs an asp.net website on it, this website makes web service calls to another IIS site over https, last night all webservice calls started failing.  I went on to the box and tried to bring up the website in IE (tried both 7 and 8) both failed with the error message "Cannot display the webpage"  I then tried Firefox on the system, and the remote HTTPS site loaded just fine.  As far as I can tell IE and by extension Windows are failing on the SSL handshake (IE receives a TCP RST command after the handshake, verified this through Wireshark.)

I'm not really sure where else to look with this issue, but any insight would be greatly beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

This may be your solution:
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-946973.html

To paraphrase: "Using Firefox, in about:config, set your SSL2 to TRUE"

In IE8, go to tools->Internet Options->Advanced(tab)->SSL 2 (enable)

Comment: unfortunately we could never find an answer to this problem, but did find out that the reason the webservice calls started failing was because on a manual error (wrong url stored in the web.config), so we gave up trying to fix it.

Comment: That's a bummer. There are a lot of configuration parameters for VMWare Server 2. It's obviously a buggy product. Nonetheless, it's free, therefore I'm grateful. :-)